# SQL Bulk insert with different types of data

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, bulkinsert

I am trying to bulk insert information from a file data.txt and in this data.txt file I have two types of rows which I can insert data from one being:

*name * description * date * date * image * image * image*

and the second being

*name * description * number of days * image * image * image*

my table in which I am trying to insert this into has columns for all of these:

*name * description * date * date * number of days * image * image * image*

but I do not know how to make it tell when it needs to insert into the number of days column or in the date columns. Also if this might help the description helps you know what will follow in the file, either dates or number of days.

I tried the normal bulk insert but just as expected I got errors telling me that the data is not inserting right

Comment: With a `BULK INSERT` the definition of the data you are `INSERT`ing must match the definition of the destination table. You could, however, create a couple of `VIEW`s with just the columns you want from your base table, and `INSERT` into those `VIEW`s. Otherwise you'd have to use staging tables.

Comment: Side note, by *image* I **hope** you don't mean the `image` data type; `image` has been deprecated for ~17 years, you really should not be using it any more.

Comment: @Larnu I put image in there as a visualization of what my table is supposed to have inside, in the image columns i have a path stored that leads to that image. No need to worry

Comment: Perhaps an `OPENROWSET(BULK` statement?